# Java - Objective C char UTF-8 issue

Tags: java, utf-8, char

I have a little issue with Java UTF-8 converting.I have this Objective C code :

```
const char *p = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%@",md5Hash] UTF8String];
```

where md5Hash is `NSString` and I need to find a way to declare the same `char p`  in Java but didn't find how to set char to UTF-8.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Objective C, but in Java chars are UTF-16 and Strings **internal** char buffer are that way. You can convert from and to UTF-8 if you need:

```
// creates a String from the bytes understanding them as UTF-8 chars
byte[] data = ...
new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

or

```
// get the bytes that would represent that string in UTF-8
String myString = "Hello";
myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Hope it helps...

**Note:** if you need an streaming solution you can also use InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter for this very same transformation but that's another story...

Comment: Conclusion: in Java if you need text use String, if you need bytes then use byte[]. You shouldn't care about the internal representation of chars/strings in Java. Only transforming from/to representation in external sources/outputs.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a String contains unicode characters, and you don't care about its encoding until you transform it to a byte array. Look at [`String.getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29). If you have a byte array and want to make it a String, you also need to specify the encoding. The String class has a constrcutor where you pass a byte array and its encoding as argument.

IO classes also have a way to write/read strings to/from a binary stream using a specific encoding. Look at the constructors of `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader`.